# Bash: How to extract parent directory of 3 files at a time

Tags: bash, awk, sed, xargs

I have file names like this:

```
/foo/bar/bazz/JMA01023D_E07/JMA01023D_E07_EKDL230054768-1A_22HFKNLT3_L4_1.fq.gz
/foo/bar/bazz/JMA01023D_E08/JMA01023D_E08_EKDL230054768-1A_22HFKNLT3_L4_1.fq.gz
/foo/bar/bazz/JMA01023D_E09/JMA01023D_E09_EKDL230054768-1A_22HFKNLT3_L4_1.fq.gz
/foo/bar/bazz/JMA01022D_E06/JMA01022D_E06_EKDL230054767-1A_22HF2WLT3_L7_1.fq.gz
/foo/bar/bazz/JMA01001D_A01/JMA01001D_A01_EKDL230054750-1A_222T7MLT4_L1_1.fq.gz
/foo/bar/bazz/JMA01001D_A02/JMA01001D_A02_EKDL230054750-1A_222T7MLT4_L1_1.fq.gz
```

3 of these files (full path, sorted alphabetically) form a triplet.
I would like to get the parent folder name for 3 files at a time.

So the desired output would be:

```
JMA01001D_A01 JMA01001D_A02 JMA01022D_E06
JMA01023D_E07 JMA01023D_E08 JMA01023D_E09
```

Something like this:

```bash
find "$@" -iname '*_1.fq.gz' | sort | xargs -I % -n3 sh -c echo % | sed -r 's/ *[^ ]*\/([^ ]+)\/([^ ]+)/\1 /g\'
```

And ideally, I would like to support spaces, so something with `find -print0`, `sort -z` and `xargs -0` would be ideal.
But I just can't seem to get it to work.

Could someone please help me untangle my brain?
It doesn't have to use sed, something with `dirname`/`basename` or `awk` would be fine as well...

Comment: What if the number of files returned by `find` is not divisible by three?

Comment: @pmf Then that’s an error and we have to abort. I’m checking with a separate call and wc -l before running this command (in fact, this output is also only needed for confirmation from the user that we got the triplets right).

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [awk](/questions/tagged/awk) to get the folder name and pipe that into [`xargs -n 3`](https://man7.org/linux/man-pages/man1/xargs.1.html) to get the output with 3 items per line:

```bash
... | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | xargs -n 3
```

---

So if I place your input in `/tmp/foo` and run the following:

```bash
sort /tmp/foo | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | xargs -n 3
```

The output is

```
JMA01001D_A01 JMA01001D_A02 JMA01022D_E06
JMA01023D_E07 JMA01023D_E08 JMA01023D_E09
```

Comment: That would fail if any of the directory names contained white space, you need `xargs -d '\n' -n 3`.

Comment: "find /foo -iname '*_1.fq.gz' | sort | awk -F'/' '{print $(NF-1)}' | xargs -d '\n' -n3" works well, thank you very much. I don't think it's needed (highly unlikely that a path would contain new lines), but just to understand the syntax, how could I make this work with `print0`?

Answer (score 4):

You can use `awk` with its built-in special variables.

- `NF` gives the number of fields (when split by what is defined with `-F`). Use it as `$(NF-1)` to get the second-to-last item, which is the parent directory of a file found.
- `NR` is the number of the record (or "line") being processed. Check it for its divisibility by three using `NR%3` to decide what to print after the parent directory.
- `OFS` and `ORS` are the output field and record (or "line") separators, which default to a space and a line break, respectively, and are printed after the parent directory, depending on whether the current item is an "inner" first or second part of the triplet, or the "final" third one.

```bash
find "$@" -iname '*_1.fq.gz' | sort |
awk -F/ '{printf "%s" (NR%3? OFS: ORS), $(NF-1)}'
```

```
JMA01001D_A01 JMA01001D_A02 JMA01022D_E06
JMA01023D_E07 JMA01023D_E08 JMA01023D_E09
```

Note: This correctly handles spaces but not line breaks occurring in the file names.

Answer (score 0):

The follwing solution uses a combination of dirname and basename:

```bash
find . -iname '*_1.fq.gz' -exec dirname {} \; | xargs basename | sort | xargs -n3
```

Comment: That would fail if any of the directory names contained white space, you need `xargs -d '\n' -n 3`.

Comment: ...or `sort -z` and `xargs -0` if you have an appropriate version or `sort`. Really any `xargs` solution should try to use null delimiters.

Comment: I like this approach for its clarity, but this would sort on the directory names. This should give the same results, but I would prefer to do the sorting on the full path...

Answer (score 0):

This might work for you (GNU parallel):

```
... | sort | parallel echo {//} | parallel -n3 echo {/}
```

or if you prefer:

```
... | sort | parallel -n3 'echo {=s#/.*/(.*)/.*#$1#=}'
```